# Android Showing two activity same time

Tags: android, android-activity, surfaceview

I have an app which shows two activities at the same time;

Because my application using surfaceview but surfaceview never accept behind view.

- FrameLayout

  - ImageView
  - SufaceView at that time i never seen ImageView by every way.

But I solve that problem by Using Two Activities.

1. Execute Activity A (Activity A (Game Background and Character))
2. Activity A intent B (Activity B (Game UI & Game Enemy))

finally I can see that I want.

My Question:

Usual Activity B is faster than Activity A because A is not focused, just showing

1. Some devices (Galaxy S2 that I know) Activity B is slower than Activity A

Plz Give me a favor 
I'm falling in this problem for 1 month....... T.T

Answer (score 1):

> I have an app which shows two activities at the same time;

I'm not sure what you mean by this because Android only allows 1 activity to run a time.
When you start Activity B from Activity A, A gets paused.

> My Question:
>
> Usual Activity B is faster than Activity A because A is not focused,
>   just showing
>
> Some devices (Galaxy S2 that I know) Activity B is slower than
>   Activity A

Again I'm not sure what this means, but as it looks like you're making a game I'd suggest you read this blogpost: http://www.rbgrn.net/content/54-getting-started-android-game-development

Maybe buy this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Android-Games-Mario-Zechner/dp/1430230428/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1304580271&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430230428)

and look at the development process/source for this game:
http://www.rbgrn.net/content/215-light-racer-3d-development-journal

Comment: Hello slayton :)

I know that Activity A life cycle is in onPause() when Activity B is focused.


But 


If Activity B(SurfaceView) has translucent background, 

Activity A is not perfectly stop and showing continuosly.

Comment: That is probably because you are not using onPause() method correctly.   Your entire game should be contained in a _SINGLE_ activity for many reasons, including its the right way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your teaching But I can't make my game without this way..... It is impossible show the ImageView under SurfaceView.... I need to show my ImageView where that is under SurfaceView... T.T If you know how can I show ImageView where under SurfaceView, plz. help me

Comment: If you use this method you're game isn't going to work. As the background activity can be killed by the OS at any time. You cannot guarantee that it is going to keep running despite the fact that you left it running. If for any reason the system needs to free up resources it can and will stop that activity.   The **best** alternative is to have a single activity with custom View class that you have written where you do the drawing yourself in the onDraw() method

Comment: I **strongly** suggest you research how to do proper game development under android rather then trying to hack together what you have. Check out the source for Replica Island and see how they do it, (Replica Island is one of the most popular open source games on android) http://code.google.com/p/replicaisland/

Comment: Thanks a lot Slayton :) You gave me much information ! This is my first time asking something to other developer :) This time I got a thinking I'm fall in wrong way...... but I can not find right way to make my game without that way... T.T

Comment: If you can't think up another way to do it then **YOU NEED** to start over by reading docs,blogs,books on how to make games. Otherwise I can guarantee your game will fail.